# What are these magic addresses in my crash reports?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, video, osx-yosemite

I maintain [cTiVo](https://github.com/dscottbuch/cTiVo/), an open-source OS X project with a large user base. On Yosemite, I started getting sporadic crash notices (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`), and I haven't been able to track them down, nor ever reproduce them on my system, nor has anyone been able to reliably recreate them in the field. Although there are a lot of reports, the crashes occur infrequently, and mostly on Yosemite (primarily 10.10.2 and 10.10.3), despite the software running on lots of other systems back to 10.7. They occur across all types of hardware (MBPro, iMac's MacMinis and others). The program doesn't do anything particularly fancy in the UI, but it does drive a lot of command-line programs (via NSTask) to do video processing and related activities.

There are two strange things about the crashes.

First is that they seem to happen across the entire program at random places both in my code and in Apple's routines. The most common (and unhelpful) is in the main run loop (see the first stacktrace below), and many of them happen within view displaying code, e.g. the second trace below. This would lead me to look for an over-released object normally, but as I said, it seems to happen to every kind of object in the program.

The second strange thing is after looking through literally hundreds of these, the invalid addresses upon which they crash almost entirely fall into one of two groups:

```
0x0000000002798000
0x0000000002998000
0x0000000002A98000
0x0000000002B98000
0x0000000003098000
0x0000000003198000
0x0000000003298000
0x0000000003398000
0x0000000003498000
0x0000000003898000
0x0000000003998000
0x0000000003A98000


0x00000000047ffff8
0x0000000004fffff8
0x00000000057ffff8
0x0000000005fffff8
0x00000000067ffff8
0x0000000006fffff8
0x00000000077ffff8
0x0000000007fffff8
```

I've stared at these for a long time, and haven't been able to figure out what this tight grouping of invalid addresses might mean. The first group are 1MiB apart and the second are 8MiB apart; AFAIK, I don't have any structures that large in my program. The second group seems to be normally distributed in frequency around 5FFFF8 as the most common. I don't see the same pattern in the first group (there might be two centers, but that may be overfitting the data). In binary, they fall into these patterns (although some of the first group don't seem to appear).

> 0000001X  XXXX1001  10000000  00000000
>   000001XX  X1111111  11111111  11111000

I should mention I also get one other error `EXC_ARITHMETIC EXC_I386_DIV at 0x0000000000000000`, again at very random places, and there doesn't seem to be any dividing going on.

Any suggestions on why these addresses appear in this patterns, that might give a clue on where to look would be great!

Here's the sample stack traces...

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff94a6a4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff9288eeb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff9288e37b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
3  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff9288dbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
4  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff94e3956f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
5  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff94e392ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
6  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff94e3912b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
7  AppKit                         0x00007fff973169bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
8  AppKit                         0x00007fff97315f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
9  AppKit                         0x00007fff9730bbf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
10 AppKit                         0x00007fff97288354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
11 cTiVo                          0x000000010871c234 start


Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff98b054de mach_msg_trap + 10
1  CoreGraphics                   0x00007fff94ccfb41 _CGSAddStructuralRegionOfType + 148
2  CoreGraphics                   0x00007fff94b29901 add_structural_region_of_type + 134
3  AppKit                         0x00007fff90647394 _NXSetCursorRect + 680
4  AppKit                         0x00007fff90646fa2 -[NSWindow _addCursorRect:cursor:forView:] + 889
5  AppKit                         0x00007fff90646c0e -[NSView addCursorRect:cursor:] + 555
6  AppKit                         0x00007fff90b1d517 -[NSTableHeaderView resetCursorRects] + 389
7  AppKit                         0x00007fff905f9ddb -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 660
8  AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
9  AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
10 AppKit                         0x00007fff905fb13e -[NSScrollView _updateTrackingAreas] + 119
11 AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
12 AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
13 AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
14 AppKit                         0x00007fff905fa21b -[NSView(NSInternal) _updateTrackingAreas] + 1748
15 AppKit                         0x00007fff90645ab9 _handleInvalidCursorRectsNote + 1072
16 AppKit                         0x00007fff90c1bd21 __35-[NSWindow _postInvalidCursorRects]_block_invoke3305 + 46
17 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff99154da7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
18 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff99154d00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
19 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff99146e08 __CFRunLoopRun + 872
20 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff99146858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
21 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff920a5aef RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
22 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff920a586a ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
23 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff920a56ab _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
24 AppKit                         0x00007fff904e5f81 _DPSNextEvent + 964
25 AppKit                         0x00007fff904e5730 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
26 AppKit                         0x00007fff904d9593 -[NSApplication run] + 594
27 AppKit                         0x00007fff904c4a14 NSApplicationMain + 1832
28 cTiVo                          0x0000000102a19234 start

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff878ff0ee objc_msgSend + 46
1  AppKit                         0x00007fff8e5519a1 -[CALayer(NSContentsAligning) NS_shouldUseContentsAligning] + 32
2  AppKit                         0x00007fff8dca1ee9 _NSBackingLayerSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 178
3  QuartzCore                     0x00007fff88e849f7 -[CALayer setNeedsDisplay] + 62
4  AppKit                         0x00007fff8dca1e10 -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 648
5  AppKit                         0x00007fff8e33a1bb NSViewSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 1077
6  WebKitLegacy                   0x00007fff89344b7e setNeedsDisplayInRect(NSView*, objc_selector*, CGRect) + 238
7  AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc36772 -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 81
8  AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc6244f -[NSTextFieldCell setObjectValue:] + 88
9  AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc61fc4 -[NSCell setStringValue:] + 111
10 AppKit                         0x00007fff8dccd250 -[NSControl setStringValue:] + 138
11 cTiVo                          0x00000001090cf92f -[MTDownloadTableView updateProgressInCell:forDL:] (MTDownloadTableView.m:158)
12 cTiVo                          0x00000001090cfc6a -[MTDownloadTableView updateProgress:] (MTDownloadTableView.m:188)
13 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8650bcdc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
14 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff863fd244 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
15 Foundation                     0x00007fff91d55c31 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
16 cTiVo                          0x000000010911cecc __93+[NSNotificationCenter(Threads) postNotificationNameOnMainThread:object:userInfo:afterDelay:]_block_invoke     (NSNotificationCenter+Threads.m:44)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8a374323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8a36fc13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x00007fff8a37bcbf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 861
20 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff864a2c79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
21 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8645f30f __CFRunLoopRun + 2159
22 CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8645e858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
23 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff926c4aef RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
24 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff926c486a ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
25 HIToolbox                      0x00007fff926c46ab _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
26 AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc26f81 _DPSNextEvent + 964
27 AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc26730 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
28 AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc1a593 -[NSApplication run] + 594
29 AppKit                         0x00007fff8dc05a14 NSApplicationMain + 1832
30 cTiVo                          0x00000001090b5714 start
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole crash report. It says there which thread is crashing, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, there's hundreds of reports, these were just a hopefully representative sample. Each of them says "Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread" (I've added the one for the third one above)

Comment: Probably a stupid question: Are you sure all UI methods are called from the main thread? (Since you are using many NSTasks) I had once a strange bug caused by such a mistake. The crash reports seem to be related to graphics.

Comment: BTW, The program does have lots of background activity going on when processing, but these issues seem to come up independently of that.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all; I spent quite a while going down that path, ensuring that those UI changes that do initiate from the background (mostly progress updates) do actually process on the foreground thread. It's still a possibility, but I think I have checked all the paths.

Comment: This is a memory management bug. You need to run your application under Instruments, using the Zombies instrument. This will flag the object that caused your crash (which is due to attempted access of an over-released object) and show you its retain/release history to help you identify the memory management bug responsible. That it happens in random locations "to random objects" doesn't rule this out.

Comment: Suspect heavily any part of your code (or third party libraries you use) that directly uses malloc() and friends. Mishandling memory of something passed to, say, a hardware-accelerated device might conceivably behave this way (a favorite region used by the system for AV-specific stuff?)...